# Google identity/button data-callback does not get trigger in Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, google-identity, nuxt3

I created a signin.vue button component in my Nuxt3 project

```
<template>
  <div
    id="g_id_onload"
    :data-client_id="config.public.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
    data-context="signin"
    data-ux_mode="popup"
    :data-callback="googleCallback"
    data-auto_prompt="false"
  ></div>

  <div
    class="g_id_signin"
    data-type="standard"
    data-shape="rectangular"
    data-theme="outline"
    data-text="signin_with"
    data-size="large"
    data-logo_alignment="left"
    data-width="384"
  ></div>
</template>

<script setup>
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const googleCallback = (response) => {
  console.log("Handle the response", response);
};

useHead({
  script: [
    {
      async: true,
      src: "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client",
      defer: true,
    },
  ],
});
</script>
```

The app renders the button correctly and I go through the steps illustrated in the guide from Google (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button). All good apart from the fact that the data-callback is not triggered and I do not see the information in the console. What's wrong with that I am doing?